# How to select whole line of text?

Tags: user-interface

Sometime there is a need to select only one line of text or paragraph from very large article?
Instead of manually enlarge the range of selection, is there an option at popup that can select line in one/two clicks? I had trouble of selecting long instruction that are outside of the screen.
Selection is in chromium based browser, (also other apps like sms reading, simple text editors). OS is Android 10 at phones with touch screen.

Comment: You should give a bit more context. What app are you asking about?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe an example in detail. Please also name the used app, and you device model + Android version.